# Reference Classes in R multiple inheritance

Tags: r, constructor, multiple-inheritance, reference-class

I have 3 reference classes on R, let call them A,B,C.
C inherits fields from both A and B but putting callSuper() in the initialize method of C this function call only A's initialize method and fields inherited from B are not initialized.

How could I do in order to initialize every field in C??

Comment: When two parent classes have the same method, than always those is called in the common subclass, which occurs first in the contains-list. The only workaround, I know, is to define `initA(...)` and `initB(..)` functions in A and B, and call each in A, B and both in C.